# Cluster Email Skip Rows with no Email included instead of getting an error message

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2010

[image]
I want to send custom emails with VBA based on a table with included Email address `strEmail`.
When there is a row with no email, I get an error message and only the first row will be send.

How can I skip rows with no Email until there is a row where `strTour_Nr` is empty.

Any ideas?

```
Sub sendCustEmails()
    
Dim objOutlook As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim objEmail As Object
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

intRow = 2
strTour_Nr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("F" & intRow).Text

While (strTour_Nr <> " ")
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'Subject and Body templates are in cells A2 and B2
    strMailSubject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A2").Text
    strMailBody = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("B2").Text
    
    strTour_Nr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("F" & intRow).Text
    strUntName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("C" & intRow).Text
    strEmail = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("P" & intRow).Text
    strVon_Ladedatum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("K" & intRow).Text
    strVon_Ladezeit = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("M" & intRow).Text
    strBis_Ladezeit = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("N" & intRow).Text
    strPOD_fehlt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("Q" & intRow).Text
    strIOP_IOD_fehlt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("R" & intRow).Text
    strPOD_missing = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("S" & intRow).Text
    strIOD_IOP_missing = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("T" & intRow).Text
    
    strMailSubject = Replace(strMailSubject, "<TourNr>", strTour_Nr)
    strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<TourNr>", strTour_Nr)
    strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<Unt_Name>", strUntName)
    strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<Von_Ladedatum>", strVon_Ladedatum)
    strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<Von_Ladezeit>", strVon_Ladezeit)
    strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<Bis_Ladezeit>", strBis_Ladezeit)
    strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<POD_fehlt>", strPOD_fehlt)
    strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<IOP_IOD_fehlt>", strIOP_IOD_fehlt)
    strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<POD_missing>", strPOD_missing)
    strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<IOP_IOD_missing>", strIOD_IOP_missing)       
    
    With objEmail
        .To = CStr(strEmail)
        .Subject = strMailSubject
        .Body = strMailBody
        .Send            
    End With
    
    intRow = intRow + 1
    strTour_Nr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren").Range("F" & intRow).Text

Wend

End Sub
```

`On Error Resume Next` seem to work but I don't know how/where to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your `Worksheet` object and then by using `With` statement you can make your code shorter and easier to read.

I replaced your `While` loop condition with a regular `For`.

See comments within code notes below:

```
Sub sendCustEmails()
        
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, intRow As Long
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     
    ' set worksheet object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Ansprechpartner für Touren")
      
    LastRow = ws.Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row ' get last row with data in worksheet
     
    With ws
        ' loop over rows with data in column F
        For intRow = 2 To LastRow
            If Trim(.Range("F" & intRow).Value) <> "" Then  ' check that column F contains text in it
                        
                Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            
                'Subject and Body templates are in cells A2 and B2
                strMailSubject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A2").Value
                strMailBody = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("B2").Value
                
        
                strTour_Nr = .Range("F" & intRow).Value
                strUntName = .Range("C" & intRow).Value
                strEmail = .Range("P" & intRow).Value
                strVon_Ladedatum = .Range("K" & intRow).Value
                strVon_Ladezeit = .Range("M" & intRow).Value
                strBis_Ladezeit = .Range("N" & intRow).Value
                strPOD_fehlt = .Range("Q" & intRow).Value
                strIOP_IOD_fehlt = .Range("R" & intRow).Value
                strPOD_missing = .Range("S" & intRow).Value
                strIOD_IOP_missing = .Range("T" & intRow).Value
                
                strMailSubject = Replace(strMailSubject, "<TourNr>", strTour_Nr)
                strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<TourNr>", strTour_Nr)
                strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<Unt_Name>", strUntName)
                strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<Von_Ladedatum>", strVon_Ladedatum)
                strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<Von_Ladezeit>", strVon_Ladezeit)
                strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<Bis_Ladezeit>", strBis_Ladezeit)
                strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<POD_fehlt>", strPOD_fehlt)
                strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<IOP_IOD_fehlt>", strIOP_IOD_fehlt)
                strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<POD_missing>", strPOD_missing)
                strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<IOP_IOD_missing>", strIOD_IOP_missing)
                
                With objEmail
                    .To = CStr(strEmail)
                    .Subject = strMailSubject
                    .Body = strMailBody
                    .Send
                End With
                
                Set objEmail = Nothing ' clear object
        
            End If
            
        Next intRow
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I get this error message: 
"Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Recipients must be specified. Ensure that you enter at least one name."

Comment: @user19600963 do you have valid email addresses? Can you share a screenshot of the worksheet and column F? you can use fake email addresses.

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot to the post. I have a formula in column P which checks if the email is valid. If valid, the email gets inserted into Column P. Is that a problem?

Comment: @user19600963 according to your screenshot there are no email addresses in column F, but column P ? where do you save the email addresses you want to use?

Comment: This now worked for me: https://imgur.com/a/VGijLan

Comment: @user19600963 that's great. I my code helped you don't forget to mark it as "answer" by posing the little check-mark next to it.